# jquery load array parameter to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass long array from jquery load to spring controller. I have passed string variable succefully but not the array.

javascript:

```
function ModuleMemberCheckboxPassIds(){
     var memberUserIds = [];
     var memberNames = [];
     $('.membercheckbox:checked').each(function(i){      
         memberUserIds[i] = $(this).val();
     });
     alert(memberUserIds.length);
     $( "#onetextarea" ).load('/assign_task', {"memberUserIds":memberUserIds,  "testdata": "test", });   
}
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/assign_task")
    public String viewAssignTask(Model model, String testdata, HttpServletRequest request){

        if(request.getAttribute("memberUserIds")==null) System.out.println("null"); else System.out.println("not null"); //returns null

        System.out.println("test: " + testdata);//returns a value

        model.addAttribute("transferVO", new TransferVO());
        return "module/view-members-checkbox";
    }
```

In **viewAssignTask** method I was able to read tesdata variable that was sent from jquery. But **memberUserIds** returns null

please help

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting an incoming JSON object on the server? If so you could try using $.ajax instead of $.load:

```
var data={"memberUserIds":memberUserIds,"testdata": "test"};

$.ajax({
    url: '/assign_task',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(html) {
        $("#onetextarea").html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: GET did not work, i had to change it to post.
I don't know why but I had to write this
data: JSON.stringify(eval({"memberUserIds":memberUserIds ,"testdata":"test"})),

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
request.getParameterValues("memberUserIds");
```

for getting multivalued Parameters.

Otherwise:

One suggestion you want to use features of Spring MVC then code should be :

```
RequestMapping(value="/assign_task")
    public String viewAssignTask(Model model, String testdata,@RequestParam String [] memberUserIds, @RequestParam String testData){
//Your Code
 }
```

Comment: request.getParameterValues("memberUserIds"); was still showing null.

I don't get it using @RequestParam was not working. Call was not directed to this controller.
@RequestMapping(value="/assign_task")
 public String viewAssignTask(Model model,@RequestParam String[] memberUserIds,@RequestParam String testdata){ ...}
Javascript call:
$( "#onetextarea" ).load('/hamdan/module/assign_task', {"memberUserIds":memberUserIds, "testdata": "test", });

Comment: there is no error message. Code is fine. I think request couldn't find which contoller and path the request should be dispatched

Comment: may be URL of the request is wrong. so try to add absolute path load('localhost:8080/myapp_/assign_task'